# How to scale back element from scaled up size?

Tags: javascript

I have the following function which increases the size of circles but instead of starting over after they were scaled, I want to scale back to original size. Backwards. So when it reached scale 2, it should go back incrementally to 1.

How can I accomplish this?

```
function animateCircles() {
  var circles = document.getElementsByClassName('circle')
  setTimeout(function () {
    for(i=0;i<circles.length;i++) {
      circles[i].animate([
        // keyframes
        { transform: 'translateY(0px)' }, 
        { transform: 'scale(2)' }
      ], { 
        // timing options
        duration: 2000,
        iterations: Infinity
      });
    }
  },0)
  setTimeout(function () {
    for(i=0;i<circles.length;i++) {
      circles[i].animate([
        // keyframes
        { transform: 'translateY(0px)' }, 
        { transform: 'scale(1.5)' }
      ], { 
        // timing options
        duration: 2000,
        iterations: Infinity
      });
    }
  },2000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another keyframe within your first animation (and adjust time accordingly):

```js
function animateCircles() {
  var circles = document.getElementsByClassName('circle')
  setTimeout(function() {
    for (i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
      circles[i].animate([
        // keyframes
        {
          transform: 'translateY(0px)'
        }, {
          transform: 'scale(2)'
        }, {
          transform: 'scale(1)'
        }
      ], {
        // timing options
        duration: 2000,
        iterations: Infinity
      });
    }
  }, 0)

}
animateCircles();
```

```css
.circle {
  background-color: #F00;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```